# Linux, BASH launch command with special char

Tags: linux, bash, sap-commerce-cloud

I must implement a deploy script that launches command by special char from specific user.

The command that I must launch is:

```
cd /path
. ./setantenv.sh
```

I am trying to launch the command with this syntax:

```
su - USER -s /bin/bash -c 'cd /PATH/ && . ./setantenv.sh'
su - USER -s /bin/bash -c 'cd /PATH/ && ant clean all'
```

But I've got a problem with `. ./setantenv.sh`

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: Which of these characters is special?  We all are unique, you know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to configure the environment for your subsequent ant command, you have to include the ". ./setantenv.sh" inside your second call. Both calls result in independent bash processes that dont share their specific environment.

try this:

```
su - USER -s /bin/bash -c 'cd /PATH/ && . ./setantenv.sh && ant clean all'
```